# Invalid APK package. Tried everything I've found, nothing works

Tags: android, apk, adb

Here's the problem when I try to debug my app over:

```
[2012-09-05 15:37:57 - Applicy] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-09-05 15:37:57 - Applicy] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-09-05 15:37:57 - Applicy] Launch canceled!
```

Here's the logcat:

```
?:??: W/?(?): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory
```

Here's what I've done:

1. Enabled root access to ADB and Apps
2. Allowed unknown sources
3. Tried it over USB instead of over a network.
4. Restarting ADB, my phone and eclipse.
5. Checked that my target SDK is okay.  My phone is running Jelly Bean and the app is API Level 10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have had this happen, especially when I have had more than one device connected to USB at the same time.  Regardless, doing a full clean/build cycle usually resolved it.  Is it just for this project or do they all do this?

Comment: You might want to do a few other things as well, if your using an alternate ROM that has been and issue on some phones, you could also try creating a new project from you existing source (assuming all of them don't do this) or renaming the package and trying a full clean/build of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is rather simple:
The LogCat is not activated, thus there is no log folder on the system. This can be due to using a non-stock kernel, like SpeedMod.
They deactivate logging for performance reasons.

You can activate logging by doing the following commands:

> [HOW TO ENABLE LOGCAT]
>
> If you are a developer or want to re-enable logcat for whatever
>   reason, do this:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo ANDROIDLOGGER >> /system/etc/tweaks.conf
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

Restart your device and the logcat logging works again. The error will be gone. (though others will eventually come up)

[SpeedMod -> 3rd post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/orig-development/kernel-speedmod-sgs2-ics-t1574218)